# Converting a text file into std::vector<string>

Tags: c++

I want a vector document variable that will look like

```
document[0] = "I"
document[1] = " "
document[2] = "want"
document[3] = " "
document[4] = "cake"
document[5] = "."
document[6] = "\n"
```

With the given line in the file "I want cake.\n"

I'm not sure how to go about doing this and everything I found on delimiters will get rid of whitespace or something.

I have an unordered_set of stopwords that I want to remove from a file. The method I have set up will iterate over a vector and remove_if the word is in my stop words.

The goal is to put all the elements in the document vector into a new file without the stop words.

```
std::vector<string> MakeFileVector(string filename){
//Get the input from the file
std::ifstream input(filename.c_str());
std::vector<string> doc;
string line;

//For each line in the text File
for ( line ; getline( input, line );)
{
    //somehow split up each word/space/period/comma/newline char
    //and add to the doc vector
    //for each word/space/period/comma/newline char
    doc.push_back(str)
}
return doc;
}
```

Comment: added some more explanation

Comment: If there's 2 spaces between `I` and `want`, should it be `"I", " ", " ", "want"` or what

Comment: that shouldn't matter for my purposes, it could be "  " with two spaces inside one string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>    

ifstream myfile("textline.txt");    

    std::vector<std::string> myLines;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myfile),
                  std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                  std::back_inserter(myLines));
```

Here you go!

Comment: This is close, but it still stores things like "rate." I want something that will store "rate" in one index, and it's "." in another

Answer (score 0):

You can use **std::noskipws** found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/). This will make sure that whitespaces are not skipped when reading from the stream. Alternatively, you can also use **std::getline**, found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to get the line into your std::string and then do your processing of whitespaces.